# Finding the first word of a form input

Tags: javascript, html

So I am working on a personal project, and so far have come up with this (see below), I was wondering rather than using an if statement for "aatrox cost" and every other champion in league of legends, I wondered if it would be possible to *see if cost was in the search* and pull the first word from the search (in this case aatrox) and put it within the "_cost.length" and "_cost[counter]"

```
else if(document.getElementById("search_data").value=="aatrox cost") {
    for (counter=0; counter<aatrox_cost.length; counter++)
        document.getElementById("search_result").innerHTML+=(aatrox_cost[counter] + "<br />")
}
```

Yes this project is league of legends based :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at IndexOf that might be what you are looking for

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var name;
var search_data = document.getElementById("search_data").value;
if(search_data.search("cost") != -1) {
    name = search_data.split(" ")[0];    
}
```

In the variable name should be whatever the first word in search_data is.